# Script to increase/decrease brightness

Tags: brightness

My keyboard doesn't have the Fn key also on Openbox I am not sure if that works.

I can use:

```
# Default 1 ignores monitor setting, allows increasing a lot. <br>
xrandr --output DP-2 --brightness 0.9
# Set 90% of brightness (parameter 10) changing the monitor setting, max 100%.
ddcutil --display 1 setvcp 10 90
```

What script or maybe just a complex command can allow me to increase/decrease the brightness by let's say 5%?

`xbacklight` and `brightnessctl` don't work and don't show any error.

I don't have any file in `/sys/class/backlight`, so it seems that my monitor doesn't have backlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ddcutil Documentation on [setvcp](https://www.ddcutil.com/command_setvcp/):

> It is possible to specify a relative instead of absolute value for a continuous feature by putting " + " or " - " between the feature id and value.
>
> - The plus or minus signs must surrounded by spaces to indicate a relative value operation.
> - The new value is adjusted so that it is never less than 0 or greater than the maximum value of the feature.
> - In this situation setvcp first reads the current value before writing the adjusted value.
>
> For example, to adjust the brightness value up or down by 5:
>
> ```
> $ ddcutil setvcp 10 + 5
> $ ddcutil setvcp 10 - 5
> ```

The documentation also states:

> In full generality, the new-value argument to setvcp is a 2 byte number. A handful of monitors have continuous features with values greater than 255. Also, the settable VCP feature x73 (Gamma) has a complex 2 byte encoding. Other than these exceptional casess, all settable values are integer values in the range 0..255, i.e. a single byte.

Comment: Using a value of 90 DOES set the brightness to 90%, at least on my monitor.

Comment: I guess the response may not be linear or have other manufacturer-specific quirks.  I added the entire section from the documentation and removed my final comment.